# JPA2/Hibernate partial composite primary as a foreign key in one to many relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0, hibernate-mapping

I can't persist the foreign keys on my tables and I think it can be a mapping problem. I am using JPA2/Hibernate4

The data model (unchangeable) is as follows:

```
OBJECTIVES
==========
INTCODE (PK)
INTOBJECTIVE (PK)
DESCRIPTION

REGISTER
========
INTCODE (PK)
INTREGISTER (PK)    
...
INTOBJECTIVE (FK from Objectives)
```

As you can see in the data model I have a composite primary key in `OBJECTIVES` table (INTCODE, INTOBJECTIVE) and only one of its fields (INTOBJECTIVE) is a foreign key in `REGISTER` table.

My JPA mapping clases is as follows:

#### OBJECTIVES CLASS

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "OBJECTIVES", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "INTOBJECTIVE"))
public class Objectives implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EmbeddedId
    @AttributeOverrides({ @AttributeOverride(name = "intcode", column = @Column(name = "INTCODE", nullable = false, length = 2)),
    @AttributeOverride(name = "intobjective", column = @Column(name = "INTOBJECTIVE", unique = true, nullable = false, precision = 22, scale = 0)) })
    private ObjectivesId id; 
    @Column(name = "DESCRIPTION")
    private String description;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="objective", fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private List<Register> registers;

    // Constructors, getters and setters ...
```

#### OBJECTIVES KEY CLASS

```
@Embeddable
public class ObjectivesId implements Serializable {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   @Column(name = "INTCODE", nullable = false, length = 2)
   private String intcode;
   @Column(name = "INTOBJECTIVE", unique = true, nullable = false, precision = 22, scale = 0)
   private BigDecimal intobjective;
   // Constructor, getters and setters, ...
```

#### REGISTER CLASS

```
@Entity
@Table(name="REGISTER", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "INTREGISTER"))
public class Register {

   @EmbeddedId
   @AttributeOverrides({ @AttributeOverride(name = "intcode", column = @Column(name = "INTCODE", nullable = false, length = 2)),
   @AttributeOverride(name = "intregister", column = @Column(name = "INTREGISTER", unique = true, nullable = false, precision = 22, scale = 0)) })
   private RegisterId id;

   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumns({
      @JoinColumn(name="INTCODE", referencedColumnName="INTCODE", insertable=false, updatable=false),
      @JoinColumn(name="INTOBJECTIVE", referencedColumnName="INTOBJECTIVE", insertable=false, updatable=false)
   })
   private Objectives objective;

   // Constructor, getter and setters, ...
```

#### REGISTER KEY CLASS

```
@Embeddable
public class RegisterId implements Serializable {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   @Column(name = "INTCODE", nullable = false, length = 2)
   private String intcode;
   @Column(name = "INTREGISTER", unique = true, nullable = false, precision = 22, scale = 0)
   private BigDecimal intregister;
   // Constructor, getters and setters, ...
```

Is it posible to perform this in Hibernate4?

Comment: INTCODE must be part of the foreign key for table REGISTER because only INTCODE  + INTOBJECTIVE is the primary key of OBJECTIVE table (and unique by definition). You say that to hibernate with the join colum in the register class... Note: AttributeOverrides is not requires because you use the same name for columns!